# Mongodb: Return cases where only one specific array value exists

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection along the lines of:-

```
(1) myCollection.tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']
(2) myCollection.tags = ['tag1', 'tag3', 'tag4']
(3) myCollection.tags = ['tag1']
(4) myCollection.tags = ['tag2', 'tag4', 'tag5']
```

How would I get my resultset specifically only satisfying the condition = 'tag1', i.e. only those such as case (3)?

Comment: You can try `db.collectionname.find({'tags' :['tag1']})`

Comment: Also `var tags = ['tag1']; db.collection.find({ "tags": { "$all": tags, "$size": tags.length } })` in a flexible JavaScript variable kind of way with the implicit AND syntax on the same key. That would match on the variable array length with elements in any order. So `var tags = ['tag5','tag2','tag4']; db.collection.find({ "tags": { "$all": tags, "$size": tags.length } })` matches your (4) condition here even though the array  is not an "exact match" because of the different order but the actual elements contained are.

Comment: In brief. You should use [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) in preference to "exact match" unless you specifically mean that to be the case where the "order" is important as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, it really was as simple as not knowing that I could use array brackets in there...
Additional thanks to @NeilLunn for the additional information - that's great to know when querying for multiple tags (which I shall also need).